# how to fix git annex function in bash?

Tags: git, bash, function

```
function checkGitAnnex
{
  echo "GIT ANNEX INFO:"
  echo "`git annex version`" 

  annex_init=echo `cd $GIT_REPO git annex init`
  if [[ $annex_init != *"ok"* ]]; then
      echo "ERROR with git annex init!"
      echo $annex_init
      echo -e "\t- Error with git annex init." >> err_message.txt
  else
      echo "init ok!"
  fi
}
```

But this execution gives me an empty value of $annex_init

p.s. normal execution of command: git annex is:

```
user@server156:~/some_project$ git annex init
init  
pre-commit hook (../../some_project/.git/hooks/pre-commit) already exists, not configuring
ok
```

Comment: `cd "$GIT_REPO"; annex_init=$(git annex init)`

Comment: You could always do `cd -` after or `pushd "$GIT_REPO"` and then `popd`

Comment: Then `annex_init=$(cd "$GIT_REPO"; git annex init)`

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni The command runs in a subshell anyway (or at least that's how I interpret the OP's intention) so there is no need to "undo" the `cd`.  The parent shell's working directory will remain unaffected.

Comment: Yes I was just re-reading that part :D, thanks for the clarification though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple bugs and stylistic errors.  Here is a minimally fixed version.

```
checkGitAnnex () {   # Fix: Use POSIX-compatible function syntax
  echo "GIT ANNEX INFO:"
  git annex version  # Fix: Remove useless echo and backticks

  annex_init=$(cd "$GIT_REPO" && git annex init)  # Fix: Assignment, quoting, cd &&
  if [[ $annex_init != *"ok"* ]]; then
      echo "ERROR with git annex init!"
      echo "$annex_init"  # Fix: Proper quoting
      echo -e "\t- Error with git annex init." >> err_message.txt
  else
      echo "init ok!"
  fi
}
```

Generally, you should probably examine the exit code from `git annex` instead of looking for the string `ok`.  This simplifies the code substantially:

```
  if annex_init=$(cd "$GIT_REPO" && git annex init); then
      echo "init ok!"
  else
      echo "ERROR with git annex init!"
      echo "$annex_init"
      printf "\t- Error with git annex init.\n" >> err_message.txt
  fi
```

Capturing the output from `git annex` only to echo it back in slightly refactored form only when there is an error is somewhat ... curious.  But then removing the chatty parts to make this "programmer friendly" basically reduces the entire function to the simple commands `git annex version; cd "$GIT_REPO" && git annex init`.